# How can I set a variable variable from within a function in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, scope

I am making a form, some of which is optional. To show the output of this form, I want to be able to check whether a POST variable has contents. If it does, the script should make a new normal PHP variable with the same value and name as the POST variable, and if not it should make a new normal PHP variable with the same name but the value "Not defined". This is what I have so far:

```
function setdefined($var)
{
    if (!$_POST[$var] == "")
    {
        $$var = $_POST[$var]; // This seems to be the point at which the script fails
    }
    else
    {
        $$var = "Not defined";
    }
}
setdefined("email");
echo("Email: " . $email); // Provides an example output - in real life the output goes into an email.
```

This script doesn't throw any errors, rather just returns "Email: ", with no value specified. I think this is a problem with the way I am using variable variables within a function; the below code works as intended but is less practical:

```
function setdefined(&$var)
{
    if (!$_POST[$var] == "")
    {
        $var = $_POST[$var];
    }
    else
    {
        $var = "Not defined";
    }
}
$email = "email"; // As the var parameter is passed by reference, the $email variable must be passed as the function argument
setdefined($email);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.array.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: Read those three ^ and I'm pretty sure we you will find your answer.

Comment: Read links suggested by @PeeHaa - especially the first one, which deals with scope. Basically, your problem comes from the fact that the new variable is only available inside the setdefined function.

Comment: The `!` binds more tightly than the `==`, so the logic is bad too:  `$var = ""; var_dump(!$var == "");`  prints `bool(false)`

Comment: Really you want `$_POST[$var] != ""`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Overlooked that one. Nice find. Looks like OP has even more reading to do: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you do it this way:

```
function setdefined($var)
{
    if (isset($_POST[$var]) && !empty($_POST[$var]))
    {
        return $_POST[$var];
    }
    else
    {
        return "Not defined";
    }
}
$email = setdefined('email');
echo("Email: " . $email);
```

The variable you create in first example is only available inside the function

Comment: I wouldn't use empty tho, because it will return TRUE if $_POST[$var] == 0

Comment: That's a better way of doing it, I didn't know about the empty function but thanks for the introduction!

Comment: Hmmm. At least add some check to verify the index exists AND it has a value to make sure you don't get warnings on e.g. checkboxes. Good and valid point though. In any case feel free to edit my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make that unknown variable submitted by possibly malicious user, global one. To do so, add this to the start of your function:

```
global $$var ;
```

This is not only ugly, but maybe unsafe too.